# Sockets burn out on light fixture

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, socket

I have a ceiling fixture that uses three 40w candelabra-base bulbs. It was burning out bulbs frequently (about one per month). Over time, two sockets were not working (confirmed with a meter test) and I rewired the fixture with a three socket harness. After a few months, a bulb blew out and when I changed the bulb, found the socket wasn't working. Any thoughts on what could be causing this and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

By "meter test", I assume you mean a voltage reading from side to base contacts. By "rewired" I assume replaced?

Heat will expand the socket base. Pull the base tabs down to create a tighter contact. Using sandpaper, scuff the bulb ends that meet the contact. Bad connections create higher amperage draw, which yields more heat, thus burn-out.

Again, I'm assuming that all wires are connected internally and are very secure with proper wire nuts.  Good luck.

Comment: Bad bulb connection multiple times, and with several different sockets? Possible, but I suspect a supply voltage issue.

Comment: Yes, I used a multimeter to take a voltage reading and confirm the socket has no power, so it's not a bad connection between the bulb and socket. Thanks Isherwood for the supply voltage suggestion. I'll look into that.